# MySQL: Exclude column based on value

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database that has a row called shapes and contains entries with either rectangles, squares and circles. I currently have the following code to get only get the shape that the user requests. (Currently it's either rectangles and circles, squares and circles or only circles). For some reason, it's not working and throwing a database error. Can anyone help me?
"MEMBER_FROM" is the column they're under

```
$where = "";
    if($context['no_sq'] == 1 && $context['no_rec'] == 0) {
        $where .= " WHERE MEMBER_FROM != 'Square'";
    } else if($context['no_sq'] == 1 && $context['no_rec'] == 0) {
        $where .= " WHERE MEMBER_FROM != 'Rectangle'";
    } else if($context['no_sq'] == 1 && $context['no_rec'] == 1) {
        $where .= " WHERE MEMBER_FROM != 'Square' AND MEMBER_FROM != 'Rectangle'";
    }
    $request = mysql_query("SELECT ID_SHAPES FROM {$db_prefix}shapes WHERE ID_MEMBER = {$memID}{$where}", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Comment: why is the first key `no_squ`? Shouldn't it be `no_sq` instead?

Comment: what is the `a database error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't say WHERE twice. Use AND...

```
   $where = "";
        if($context['no_squ'] == 1 && $context['no_rec'] == 0) {
            $where .= " AND MEMBER_FROM != 'Square'";
        } else if($context['no_sq'] == 1 && $context['no_rec'] == 0) {
            $where .= " AND MEMBER_FROM != 'Rectangle'";
        } else if($context['no_sq'] == 1 && $context['no_rec'] == 1) {
            $where .= " AND MEMBER_FROM != 'Square' AND MEMBER_FROM != 'Rectangle'";
        } 

     $request = mysql_query("SELECT ID_SHAPES FROM {$db_prefix}shapes WHERE ID_MEMBER = {$memID}{$where}", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

**UPDATE:**
Based on your statement that your shapes are exclusion checkboxes it would make more sense to name those boxes in an array then build your query based on a loop. Otherwise this code could be very hard to maintain...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="exclude[]" value="Square"> Square
<input type="checkbox" name="exclude[]" value="Rectangle"> Rectangle
<input type="checkbox" name="exclude[]" value="Circle"> Circle
```

then in PHP

```
foreach($_POST['exclude'] AS $exclude)
{
    $where .= " AND MEMBER_FROM != '".$exclude."'";
}
```

... obviously escaping that $exclude var, but for simplicity let's assume you are escaping user input.

Comment: My statement is simply that you can't use WHERE twice. Your personal  problem is how you're constructing your query. If you want to select a shape based on the user's request why don't you say MEMBER_FROM = 'whatever shape they ask for' and not specifically excluding based on whatever this $context arr is? In order to optimize we would need to know more about how you're gathering the user input.

Comment: In the actual thing, there are more shapes, but I decided to simplify it for experimental sake. It is easier to exclude than include shapes. They're clicking which ones they exclude via a tick box.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding multiple `WHERE` clauses to your query, which is illegal. Additionally, you may like the syntax of `NOT IN` better in this case. Note that I also took the liberty of cleaning up your logical structure a bit.

```
$sql = "SELECT ID_SHAPES FROM {$db_prefix}shapes WHERE ID_MEMBER = {$memID}";
$disallowed = array();
if($context['no_squ']) $disallowed[] = 'Square';
if($context['no_rec']) $disallowed[] = 'Rectangle';
if(count($disallowed)) {
    $sql .= 'AND MEMBER_FROM NOT IN ("' . implode('", "', $disallowed) . '")';
}
$request = mysql_query($sql);
```